# Which web browsers send ping/pong requests in their websocket connections?

Tags: browser, websocket

I wrote a websocket server but neglected to implement the PING/PONG command. It worked, however I noticed in my logs the server occasionally crashed because one or more clients had sent a PING/PONG request.

Is there a list of web browsers that send PING/PONG requests on their websocket connections?

Comment: I would expect just about all of them to, since it part of the WebSocket protocol.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - as a server implementor, I never noticed a browser initiating a `ping`. They all `pong` back, but the ones I work with (safari, chrome) don't `ping`... I think maybe Firefox was the exception. It might have sent a `ping`, though I'm not too sure about it either.

Comment: this thread will help to understand 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706002